# Unable to set gradient color to DOM Elements through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

can we set -moz-linear-gradient through javascript. Unable to set gradient color to dropdown items in menu bar. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/586Ru/) is the JSFiddle

```
var coll = document.getElementById('menu-preview').getElementsByClassName('dropdown-1column');
 if ( coll != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].style.backgroundImage = "-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1f471, #ffcc33)";
        coll[i].style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,    
          from(#f1f471), to(#ffcc33))";
        coll[i].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(top, #f1f471, #ffcc33)";
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE-7-25:2322IS**

I even tried JQuery way still no luck, some how gradient not reflecting for DOM items created runtime

```
                $('#backcolor').on('change', function () {
                var color = $(this).val();
                document.getElementById("menu-preview").style.backgroundColor = color;
                var gradient = getSimilarColors(color);
                $('.dropdown-1column').css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + color + ',' + gradient + ')');
                $('.dropdown-1column').css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(' + color + '),' + 'to(' + gradient + '))');
                $('.dropdown-1column').css('background', 'linear-gradient(top,' + color + ',' + gradient + ')');
            });
```

**UPDATE 7-25:2335IS**

Thanks @nsthethunderbolt for correcting issue with typo taken almost half a day...should be dropdown1-column instead dropdown-1column. Thanks man, you saved my day!

Comment: The issue appears to be with readonly collection but how to overcome this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/586Ru/4/

and

```
    var coll = document.getElementById('menu-preview').getElementsByClassName('dropdown1-column');
console.log(coll)
                if ( coll != null) {
                 //   console.log(coll)
                    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
coll[i].style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1f471, #ffcc33)";

coll[i].style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f1f471), to(#ffcc33))";
coll[i].style.background = "linear-gradient(top, #f1f471, #ffcc33)";
                    }
                }
```

works well, but your dropdown hovering is not correct, you have to work on that.

Comment: No, this is not what I want. The requirement is to set gradient color to dropdown items which appear while mouse hover on menu item

Comment: OK, updated the link... and dropdown1-column was misspelled in your code.

Comment: You know what I was really going crazy for hours on this, you saved my day. Thanks a lot.